# Line break automatically after 7 displayed divs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I need to display div's equal in height and width with AngularsJS that needs to make a 7x5 square:

```
----------------------
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
----------------------
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
----------------------
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
----------------------
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
----------------------
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
----------------------
```

I could easily use `flex` and `md-wrap` to have this automatically breakline, but it's not possible with 7 div's in a row. Because:
container = 100%
container/7 = 14.28
but values can only be 10 or 15!

I need to use Angular, so I need this structure:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in Ctrl.items">
     {{item}}
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at the twitter bootstrap [twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) css. they have a great grid. And this discussion about a 7 column grid. [7 column grid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955088/7-equal-columns-in-bootstrap)

Comment: Foundation is another alternative. You can customize the number of columns. http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html#customize-with-sass

Comment: I'm using angular materiel design. I can't use two designs. Angular material is not as mature as Bootstrap, but I think it has more potential.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the CSS:

```
div:nth-of-type(8n) {
...
}
```

to give every 8th div a specific display behaviour

(eg. using either `clear` or `flex`).

Example:

```
div {
float: left;
}

div:nth-of-type(8n)::before {
 visibility: hidden;
 display: block;
 font-size: 0;
 content: " ";
 clear: left;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it should work. I've not tried it, so do come back and let us know if it needed any tweaking. Happy to help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the nth-child and after pseudo selcetors, [as demonstrated in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f0xL6khy/):

```
div {
    display:inline;
}
div:nth-child(7n) {
    color:red
}
div:nth-child(7n):after {
    content:' ';
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: I need al div's to be bordered, it seems 7nth div isn't http://jsfiddle.net/f0xL6khy/1/