# In AngularJS how do I generate a grid 7x7 from a given array of objects in a sequence?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have an array of objects say like this

```Js
var card = [
    {name:'square',color:'red'},
    {name:'triangle',color:'black'},
    {name:'circle',color:'blue'},
    {name:'oval',color:'yellow'},
    {name:'pentagon',color:'green'}
]
```

I want to generate a grid of 7x7 in horizontal sequence as per the shapes above and show the name of each, since the array only has 5 objects, I'd like to after 5th element, start from the first object again, say like this

```Js
SQUARE   | TRIANGLE |  CIRCLE  |   OVAL   | PENTAGON |  SQUARE  | TRIANGLE
CIRCLE   |   OVAL   | PENTAGON |  SQUARE  | TRIANGLE |  CIRCLE  | OVAL
PENTAGON |  SQUARE  | TRIANGLE |  CIRCLE  |   OVAL   | PENTAGON | SQUARE
TRIANGLE |  CIRCLE  |   OVAL   | PENTAGON |  SQUARE  | TRIANGLE | CIRCLE
OVAL     | PENTAGON |  SQUARE  | TRIANGLE |  CIRCLE  |   OVAL   | PENTAGON
SQUARE   | TRIANGLE |  CIRCLE  |   OVAL   | PENTAGON |  SQUARE  | TRIANGLE
CIRCLE   |   OVAL   | PENTAGON |  SQUARE  | TRIANGLE |  CIRCLE  | OVAL
```

Comment: This is a pretty broad request, and it's not really a question.  "I want to..." isn't a question, it is a statement that implies you are hoping someone else will write a complete solution for a problem you haven't tried to solve yourself.  That isn't how this site works.  Instead, you should summarize what you have tried, and the challenges you are having with your attempts.  Also see [ask].

Comment: You need to create the 2 dimensional array then you can easily create the grid.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

```
var card = [
    {name:'square',color:'red'},
    {name:'triangle',color:'black'},
    {name:'circle',color:'blue'},
    {name:'oval',color:'yellow'},
    {name:'pentagon',color:'green'}
]

var gridData= [];
var itemSize = 7*7;
while (gridData.length < itemSize ){
    gridData= gridData.concat(card);
}

$scope.gridData = gridData.slice(0, itemSize);
```

HTML:

use an ng-repeat and bootstrap to make a 7 column grid.

for the 7 column grid, you can see here:
[7 equal columns in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955088/7-equal-columns-in-bootstrap)

Comment: This code is a bit unclear. You define `gridData`, then set `$scope.gridData` to `cardGridData`, followed by a syntax error.