# While retrieve from mysql, rows are not placing properly in second row in bootstrap grid

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<?php
    include 'connect.php';
    $sql="SELECT * FROM upload ORDER BY id asc";
    $retval=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($retval)){
    ?>

      <div class="col-sm-2"> 
      <div class="content-wrapper" style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
        <center>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo "img/".$row['bimg']?>"><br>
        Name:<?php echo $row['bname']?><br>
        Author:<?php echo $row['author']?>
        </center>
        </div>
     </div>


<?php
    }
    ?>
```

Here is my code. I am using col-md-2 x 6. In the second row of the 1'st column is showing under the 6'th column. please take a look my Image link and help me... Thanks...

[i got output like this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3fUTpTejVanS3VDcFNqYVloSHc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: <?php
 include 'connect.php';
 $sql="SELECT * FROM upload ORDER BY id asc";
 $retval=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($retval)){
 ?>

   <div class="col-sm-2"> 
   <div class="content-wrapper" style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
  <center>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo "img/".$row['bimg']?>"><br>
  Name:<?php echo $row['bname']?><br>
  Author:<?php echo $row['author']?>
  </center>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  
<?php
 }
 ?>

Answer (score 0):

So, if you use static col nubber you can just use `div.clearfix` block each 6 items.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap works in a grid of 12 so 6 columns at a width of 2 = 12 and your 7th column will naturally go to the next row.

So it's working as it should. If you need 7 rows you need to make your own class.

Take a look at this.

[7 equal columns in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955088/7-equal-columns-in-bootstrap)

Comment: thanks. but actually i need 6 columns in a row. the 1st column in the next(2'nd) row is not floating left. please help